# LaTeX Error: File `beamerugthemedefault' not found

Tags: beamer

with "pdflatex beameruserguide.tex" i tried to create beameruserguide.pdf from beamer.doc.tar.xz and got the following errors:

```
Overfull \hbox (0.189pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 283--285
[][]\T1/lmtt/m/n/10 format=$\OMS/lmsy/m/n/10 h$[]\T1/lmr/m/it/10 extension$\OMS
/lmsy/m/n/10 i$[] []\T1/lmr/m/n/10 will cause the file names for which we searc
h change from $\OMS/lmsy/m/n/10 h$[]\T1/lmr/m/it/10 base file name$\OMS/lmsy/m/
n/10 i$[][]\T1/lmtt/m/n/10 .$\OMS/lmsy/m/n/10 h$[]\T1/lmr/m/it/10 number$\OMS/l
msy/m/n/10 i$
[134] [135] [136] [137]) [138] [139] (./beamerug-themes.tex [140]

! LaTeX Error: File `beamerugthemedefault' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.65 \begin{themeexample}{default}
                                  
?
```

How can this problem be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: x-post https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/810

Answer (score 2):

The beamer user guide includes a ton of example images, which need to be build first.

I'm not sure what exactly your .doc.tar.xz archive contains, but assuming you cloned the full repository https://github.com/josephwright/beamer you can build the beamer user guide with

```
l3build doc
```

This builds all the example images for the different themes first  and then compiles the user guide.